# How to remove duplicates from specific ReportingDate only in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have columns in my BQ table like: ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service and I have 2 rows of each record, so instead of 20 i have 40 of them in ReportingDate = '2023-09-15'. How can I remove only duplicate values in this table from this specific date?
I was trying it like that:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15' AND ReportingDate IN (
  SELECT ReportingDate
  FROM my_table
  WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15'
  GROUP BY ReportingDate
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

but this will probably remove all records from this date.

Comment: Does this table have a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

To delete only duplicate values from '2023-09-15' while keeping one copy of each, you can use a subquery to select the duplicates and then delete them. Here's the modified query:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15' AND (ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service) IN (
  SELECT ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service
  FROM my_table
  WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15'
  GROUP BY ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

This query will delete duplicates from '2023-09-15' based on all the columns (ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, and Service) while keeping one copy of each unique combination of those columns.

> Make sure to take a backup or work on a test dataset before executing
> DELETE queries on production data to prevent accidental data loss.

Try another query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service ORDER BY ReportingDate) AS rn
  FROM my_table
  WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15'
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: I am receiving this error: "Subquery of type IN must have only one output column at "

Comment: Try the second query command. It would be better if you can use primary key. You can add an auto increment id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number(). Assuming you have a primary key (id) in table:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id from (
 SELECT id, row_number() over (partition by ReportingDate, Balance, Currency, Service) rn
 FROM my_table
 WHERE ReportingDate = '2023-09-15'
 ) sq where rn>1
);
```

Comment: my table doesn't have any primary key

Comment: then you can add an auto increment id and remove it after deletion if not required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete duplicates filtering with Reporting Date you can achieve from below query

```
 ;With CTE(
    Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By ReportingDate Order By ReportingDate)Rno,ReportingDate 
From My_Table
Where ReportingDate='2023-09-15'
    )
Delete From cte where rno>1
```

If you want to delete the Duplicate without filter you can achieve from below query

```
;With CTE(
    Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By ReportingDate Order By ReportingDate)Rno,ReportingDate 
From My_Table
    )
Delete From cte where rno>1
```